# Convert json to array php gives Array to string conversion

Tags: php, json

I have a json as shown below.I want to access the value of `adult`.However when i do  `echo json_decode($json_response, true);` i get `Array to string conversion`.What is wrong here ?

```
 {
      "responses": [
        {
          "safeSearchAnnotation": {
            "adult": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
            "spoof": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
            "medical": "UNLIKELY",
            "violence": "LIKELY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function `json_decode` returns an array. You can't `echo` an array, or you'll get that conversion error.

You want to use `print_r` instead:

```
print_r(json_decode($json_response, true));
```

See here: https://3v4l.org/K3UfP